# metrics for comparing training loss in same architecture

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I have two models that are training by this architecture in tensorflow, that is not necessarily required for the question, but I am including it if it was important for some readers.

I want to know if I have the same training settings, with two different sub-dataset, but from one data distribution, does it mean if one of them is training slower, it is learning more features?

```
        features = tf.placeholder(
        tf.float32, shape=[None, IMAGE_SIZE * IMAGE_SIZE], name='features')
    labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int64, shape=[None], name='labels')
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 1])
    conv1 = tf.layers.conv2d(
      inputs=input_layer,
      filters=32,
      kernel_size=[5, 5],
      padding="same",
      activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(
        inputs=pool1,
        filters=64,
        kernel_size=[5, 5],
        padding="same",
        activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, 7 * 7 * 64])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=2048, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dense, units=self.num_classes)
    predictions = {
      "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
      "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }
    loss = tf.losses.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels, logits=logits)
    # TODO: Confirm that opt initialized once is ok?
    train_op = self.optimizer.minimize(
        loss=loss,
        global_step=tf.train.get_global_step())
    eval_metric_ops = tf.count_nonzero(tf.equal(labels, predictions["classes"]))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are saying that it has the same setting, then training slower, it could mean that it is learning more. If one of them has a skewed dataset, then it might train faster on some distribution, and it can be an indication, that the training is not learning all feature of the main data distribution.